# How can get my nav link's sublist items to show on the right of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to get my nav link's sub items to pop up from the right side of the link, instead of sliding from under it using foundation's jQuery.

```
<ul class="side-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Collections</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Extreme Sports</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQ file:

```
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').children('ul').hide(); //hide submenu
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').addClass('hasChildren'); // add class to li ul child
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" ) // add active class to clicked menu item
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(); //toggle submenu
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  try doing this.

add `.collections` to the `li` and then apply `position: absolute;` style on its children.

```js
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').children('ul').hide(); //hide submenu
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').addClass('hasChildren'); // add class to li ul child
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" ) // add active class to clicked menu item
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(); //toggle submenu
});
```

```css
.collections{
  position:relative;
}

.collections ul{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  margin-left: 7rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<ul class="side-nav">
      <li class="collections"><a href="#">Collections</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Extreme Sports</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @scriptTease Cool! Glad to help. Please upvote and mark my answer as solution if this helps you.

Comment: I tried, but because I don't have 15+ rep, I'm not allowed to do so yet.

Comment: @scriptTease I see no worries. Glad that I am be able to help you out.